# IntelliJ code style customization

Tags: java, intellij-idea, configuration

How do we configure intellij code style so that when reformating code

instead of this:

[image]

we get this:
[image]

Comment: There's a great talk explaining, among other things, why the current style makes more sense than the style that you want to change it to: http://vimeo.com/97329157

Comment: However is this possible?

Comment: Your question is only concerning `java`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While working with method chaining (for example builders), you can override the default behavior of intellij idea to align chained methods. This way, in my opinion, the code is much more readable. I think you should consider it as an alternative to your proposed solution.

> Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java -> Wrapping and Braces -> Chained
>   Method Calls -> Align when multiline

**BEFORE**

[image]

**AFTER**

[image]

Comment: Not exactly what i intended, but those settings are what i was looking for.

Comment: Great. This becomes more important as `java 8 stream` often has many chaining methods.